# How do I use Proportional Edit Correctly?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, interface, edit-mode

I've tried everything to fix this. Restarting my computer, closing Blender and opening it again, uninstalling Blender and installing it again. Unless it's a bug, I don't know how to fix this. Advice anyone?

Also here's a screenshot of the issue I'm having.:
[image]

I made the mountain after selecting "Spherical Falloff", I'm trying to make a hill, and it's obvious that is no hill.

Comment: Increase the radius for proportional editing with the mouse wheel. On the image you show, the influence is so small that it only affects one vertex. By moving the moues wheel you can make the tool affect other vertices as well.

Comment: What cegaton said.  The white circle is what shows you how wide of an area you're affecting.

Comment: Oh god DUH, thanks. I keep forgetting about that since I just started using this.

Answer (score 0):

When the proportional editing tool is activated and being used useful usage information is displayed in the 3D View header.

The tool makes use of the mouse wheel for adjusting the radius of proportional influence, bigger values meaning more proportional movement.